# count the number of words said by each character in any format of movie script

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to count the number of words spoken by each character in any format of movie/tv scripts.

I adopted some code from [Counting the words a character said in a movie script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881391/counting-the-words-a-character-said-in-a-movie-script) as followed:

```py
with open('path/10_Things_I_Hate_About_You.txt','r') as f:
    s = f.read().split('\n')
    speaker = '' # current speaker
    words = 0 # number of words on line
    word_count = {} # dict of speakers and the number of words they speak

    for line in s:

        if re.match('^[ ]{33}[^ ]{1,}.*', line): # name of speaker
            speaker = line.split(' (')[0][33:].strip()
            print(speaker)
        if re.match('^[ ]{20}[^ ]{1,}.*', line): # dialogue line
            print(line)
            words = len(line.split())
            if speaker in word_count:
                 word_count[speaker] += words
            else:
                 word_count[speaker] = words
```

But this only worked for a strict kind of script format (where indent for speaker=33 and for dialogue line = 20)

I've also tried to use nltk package as followed:

```py
for line in s:
        indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        if len(line.split())<=2 and len(line.split())>0 and '<' not in line:
            tokenize = line.strip().split(' ')
            tagged_text = pos_tag(tokenize)
            speaker = ''.join(find_proper_nouns(tagged_text)) 
            print('speaker is {}'.format(speaker))

        if '\t' in line[:2]: #one type of script
            print('version 1')
            if re.match('^[\t]{2}[^ ]{1,}.*', line): # dialogue line
                print('dialogue is {}'.format(line))
                words = len(line.split())
                if speaker in word_count:
                     word_count1[speaker] += words
                else:
                     word_count1[speaker] = words

        else: #another type of script
#             print('version 2')
            if re.match('^[ ]{20}[^ ]{1,}.*', line): # dialogue line
                print(line)
#                 print('dialogue is {}'.format(line))
                words = len(line.split())
                if speaker in word_count:
                     word_count1[speaker] += words
                else:
                     word_count1[speaker] = words
```

But this still doesn't work nicely.

Here is a list of movie scripts of all kinds: https://github.com/EdinburghNLP/scriptbase/tree/master/scriptbase_alpha

I expect the code to output (maybe) a dictionary like {'a': 230, 'b':3407,'c': 40,...} with values as the total number of words spoken by each character. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Nothing you write can provably work for _any format_ of anything.  Since there are infinitely many possible formats one can use to structure a movie script, one way of going about this would be to adapt the script to several formats and find a way to tell whether a certain format is parseable by your script; if not, log that somewhere and update the code further.  Machine learning could be interesting here, too, though it might be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for inspiration! Also you mentioned machine learning, do you have anything in mind to go about this with machine learning? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example, and explain why "this still doesn't work nicely"?